# Samba and Groups

Tags: permissions, samba

Ok I've been reading about Samba shares etc. for the past few days, I still cannot get it to work.

I've gotten a public share and a private user share to work, but not a group share.

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    map to guest = bad user 
    #state directory = /var/lib/samba
    #usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares

[public]
    comment = public share
    path = /srv/abc/public
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    ready only = no
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 

[private]
    comment = private share
    path = /srv/abc/private
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    security = user
    valid users = test
    ready only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 

[mygroup]
    comment = mygroup server files
    path = /srv/mygroup
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    security = user
    valid users = @mygroup
    force group = mygroup
    ready only = no
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0777
    create directory = 0777 
    force create mode = 0777
    force security mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
```

I done the following to add a user an d group.

```
sudo useradd karl
sudo passwd karl
sudo groupadd mygroup
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup karl
sudo smbpasswd -a karl
sudo mkdir /srv/mygroup
sudo chmod 777 /srv/mygroup
sudo chgrp mygroup /srv/mygroup
sudo chown mygroup /srv/mygroup
```

I still can't log into it via my windows 8.